# ubuntu-tweak stopped working

Tags: 12.10, ubuntu-tweak

```
** (ubuntu-tweak:5760): WARNING **: Failed to load shared library 'libwebkitgtk-3.0.so.0' referenced by the typelib: libwebkitgtk-3.0.soso: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/_gobject/__init__.py:279: Warning: cannot derive `ubuntutweak+apps+AppsWebView' from non-derivable parent type `void'
  type_register(cls, namespace.get('__gtype_name__'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-tweak", line 124, in 
    from ubuntutweak.main import UbuntuTweakWindow
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/main.py", line 32, in 
    from ubuntutweak.apps import AppsPage
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/apps/__init__.py", line 99, in 
    class AppsWebView(WebKit.WebView):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 220, in __init__
    super(GObjectMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, dict_)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/_gobject/__init__.py", line 227, in __init__
    cls._type_register(cls.__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/_gobject/__init__.py", line 279, in _type_register
    type_register(cls, namespace.get('__gtype_name__'))
RuntimeError: could not create new GType: ubuntutweak+apps+AppsWebView (subclass of void)
```

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> then do as

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
```

then try again.